# Was the Metaverse based on the World Wide Web?

Tags: neal-stephenson, snow-crash

Reading through *Snow Crash* today, it's hard not to think of the Metaverse and The Street as a futuristic version of the Internet which we have today. However, given that *Snow Crash* was published in 1992, when the internet was still in its infancy, it seems likely this may be just a case of [future anachronism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anachronism#Future_anachronism).

So the question is: Was Neal Stephenson's Metaverse based in any way on the early World Wide Web?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Snow Crash was published in 1992, but it was written well before that. The [WWW was launched officially in 1991](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_World_Wide_Web) and it was still full text. The publication of the first proposal for an [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) specification dates from mid-1993. Before that, the [Internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Internet) had little in common with what we know right now. So, the Metaverse has almost nothing to do with this embryonic WWW.

[BBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletin_board_system) and [CompuServe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compuserve) were far more popular back then.

Comment: Besides. It looks Far FAR more like Second Life, mainly because Second Life means to be it.

Comment: I tried out Second Life after reading Snow Crash. I was VERY disappointed, lol. I deleted it off my Mac after about 10 mins of that crap.

Answer (score 7):

Aside from factual details in DavRob's answer, they are different applications.

WWW (as originally conceived) is a way to organize and link information (a primitive predecessor of which was [Gopher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher_%28protocol%29)).

Metaverse is a way to visually/sensually present an environment and communications. A primitive text predecessor of it would be MUDs (aka [Multi-User Dungeons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD) - text based ancestor of MMORPGs), IRC and some aspects of BBSs.

The only thing in common is that they both exist over an underlying network.

Comment: The Metaverse was more like a MUD than the WWW, but it's strongly implied that it's the standard way to do anything on the Internet in Snowcrash - much like the WWW today is used by many people in place of specialized applications for e.g. FTP, SMTP, HTTP, and IRC.

Comment: @Joe - the question was about original WWW, without even applets - never mined the AJAXified HTML5-ed modern version.